# Isight program did not read .inp file but read .cae file

Tags: optimization, abaqus, isight

I want to use Abaqus component in Isight, but it can not read `.inp` files. When I try to read `.cae` file, it reads but gives an error about rewriting input file when I run model. The error message is:

[image: error message]

I tried to example file which is already in Isight program. It worked very well. However, I opened a new work and tried to read this example's `.inp` file, it did not read. I searched on web about same problem but no one suggest any solution. Only one said the file is in lock mode. But this is not a clear solution. Could you help me to solve this problem?

The example `.inp` file can be found in the link:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rYt69ScquVVW4lJ5DF3fVRKvPRLZgQWe/view?usp=sharing

The example `.cae`, `.odb`, `.zmf` file can be found in the link also:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/13wl03icP8KR0DOQ-YC8ng0VeY0Yq9xHA/view?usp=sharing

the example `.zmf` file which is above the link, is made by me. But the link below I gave, the example from Isight. And it worked very well. But when I tried to read `.inp` file by myself, it didn't read.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MZAu9IOgdgbzSOBW-Z4lwEQq9AESK3Un/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

The execution can be failing if

- the .inp file has the *parameter command
- you have "special" characters in the .inp file
- you have empty lines in the .inp
- you have a .lck file in the same directory
- the .inp file has incompatible commands with the Isight

To debug the problem, I recommend testing with a very simple .inp file and see if there are any compatibility issues.

Comment: The .inp file is from abaqus so I didn't change anythin of it. I didn't have .lck file. I attached the .inp file could you look it for me?

Comment: please change the permissions to public so I can download the file

Comment: Sorry. I changed it public.

Comment: Did you look at the file?